# Bind TabItem Context menu Visibility to DataContext

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I am trying to bind the visibility of a context menu to a CanClose property on the data context.
The binding works for other controls in the same scope.

```
<TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.Margin>
                        <Thickness Left="0" Top="0" Right="{StaticResource LBFTabMargin}"
                           Bottom="0" />
                    </Grid.Margin>

                    <Border Background="LightGray" BorderBrush="DarkGray" BorderThickness="1" x:Name="ForegroundBorder" />
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid Margin="{StaticResource LBFSmallThickness}">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Foreground="{DynamicResource LBFTabTextBrush}"
                               FontWeight="SemiBold"
                               Margin="{StaticResource LBFSmallThickness}" MaxWidth="300"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabItem} }, Path=Content.DataContext.TabHeader}"
                               ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabItem} }, Path=Content.DataContext.TabToolTip}">

                                <TextBlock.ContextMenu >
                                    <ContextMenu Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}, Path=Content.DataContext.CanClose,Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}">
                                        <MenuItem Header="Luk alle"/>
                                        <MenuItem Header="Luk alle, undtagen denne"/>
                                    </ContextMenu>
                                </TextBlock.ContextMenu>

                            </TextBlock>
                            <Button Width="15" Height="15"
                            Style="{StaticResource CloseButtonStyle}"
                            Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}, Path=Content.DataContext.CanClose,Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}"
                            Grid.Column="1" IsHitTestVisible="True">
                                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                                        <infrastructure:CloseTabbedViewAction />
                                    </i:EventTrigger>
                                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            </Button>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="ForegroundBorder" Property="Background" Value="White" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I guess that the binding fails because the context menu is not in the visual tree. I am using snoop to check that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, context menus are not part of the visual tree. They don't inherit the same source as the control they belong to for binding. The way to deal with this is to bind to the placement target of the ContextMenu itself.
So try this:

```
<TextBlock.ContextMenu >
  <ContextMenu Visibility="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext.CanClose, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <MenuItem Header="Luk alle"/>
    <MenuItem Header="Luk alle, undtagen denne"/>
  </ContextMenu>
</TextBlock.ContextMenu>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. The key to search for is PlacementTarget. This article helped med to understand PlacementTarget http://www.spectrecoder.com/?p=51